# Find path between two nodes using Networkx library, Having single source and multiple targets?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

Hello I'm using networkx library, I have created graph but the i'm having issue in finding multiple targets and target values are bit tricky because target has to be matched with substring within the given target value.
Example:
Nodes = ['C0111', 'N6186', 'C5572', 'N6501', 'C0850-IASW-NO01', 'C1182-IUPE-NO01']
Edges = [('C0111','N6186'),('N6186','C0850-IASW-NO01'),('C0111','C5572'),('C5572','N6501'),('N6501','C1182-IUPE-NO01')]

Problem:
Source = 'C0111'
Target = ['IASW','IUPE']

Their are some special nodes which are considered as target which are 8 of them including nodes containing 'IUPE' , 'IASW' ,etc

I can create graph using networkx.

```
    import networkx as nx
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(Nodes)
    G.add_edges_from(Edges)
    nx.shortest_path(G,source='C0111',target=?)'''
```

for multiple targets i can iterate through multi targets but for substring to be in node i'm confused  on this point.

example:
normal way ==> '''nx.shortest_path(G,source='C0111',target='C0850-IASW-NO01')'''

'C0850-IASW-NO01' => thats how node is created
but i want to see if target has IASW or IUPE in it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the pattern to subset the target nodes before looking for the shortest paths:

```py
target_nodes = [n for n in G if "IASW" in str(n) or "IUPE" in str(n)]
```

With a list of target nodes, now it's possible to iterate over them and find the shortest path of interest (as you describe).